# How do I quantify the homogeneity of discrete data?

Tags: variance, discrete-data

I have a subset (of some bigger set, lets say of size $N$) containing $S$ different things. Now each of these $S$ things belong to a category. The total number of categories is $<=N$. What can be a metric that quantifies the homogeneity of the objects in my subset with respect to the categories that they belong to. Meaning, the score would be highest (lowest) when all the $S$ things belong to the same category and lowest (highest) when each of them belong to different categories.

Comment: A useful search term might be _concentration index_.

Comment: Is the number of categories K in the bigger set N known?

Comment: @dipetkov not a priori but given the data, yes

Comment: I wasn't precise enough. Say the subset is S = {a, a, b, c} but the set N contains (some number of) categories {a,b,c,d,e}. Given S, is it okay to assume that we know: #a=2, #b=1, #c=1, #d=0, #e=0. Or we only know about e&f the first time they get observed.

Answer (score 1):

One minus the number of categories in your set $S$ ($\#c(S)$) divided by the size of $S$:
$$
score(S) = 1 - \frac{\#c(S)}{\#S}.
$$

Comment: This makes sense, but the best score (obtained when all in $S$ belong to the same category) would become dependent on the size of $S$, which is not desirable. On the other hand, this giving a higher score for a larger subset which has the same number of categories included, is kind of nice in that it encodes the peculiarity of such a situation.

Comment: Arguably, a larger "pure" set should get a higher score than a small pure set (e.g. a set of just one element).